# Disable Specific JavaScript File for Specific HTML Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Suppose I have two same HTML elements (i.e video tag) on an HTML file, with a javascript file included in it.

This js file affecting both elements (there is some code written in js file that adds wrappers against video tag ).

I want this file to only affect the first element not second.

**Important Note:** I can't make any changes to that js file, but I can add any other js file or js code to achieve what I want.

Is it possible?

**Use Case:**

Well, I have been asked to add a custom feature in an existing website where I am adding some HTML elements but there are some javascript libraries that are adding some HTML tags as wrapper against my own elements.

How can I resist those javascript libraries to ignore these particular elements?
I can't make any changes in that javascript libraries. I can add my own javascript to achieve what I want.

Comment: Could you add a custom JS file that injects that video element after the libraries have been initialised and hooked onto your first video element?

Comment: Yes, I can add any custom js file, but how to do that that you described?

Comment: You'll probably want to use `document.createElement('video');` and add the appropriate attributes (`src`, etc.). Read up on DOM manipulation in JavaScript for more information.

Comment: Why don't you use id or class and apply your js to only that element?

Comment: @user3337667: It's a restriction from the client.

Comment: @chriskirknielsen: Thanks a lot for your time. Your solution really helped me. I am using the following code

   window.onload = function(){
   x=document.getElementById("elem");
   x.innerHTML="<video controls autoplay playsinline class='record-screen' 
   id='record_screen'></video>";
}